# How can I scan my entire site for every image to know each image's size and dimensions and url?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

A client wants to know the size and dimensions of *every* image on their wordpress site and where they are located (URL). I'm a jr developer tasked with this and I truly have no idea where to start. I was hoping to find some sort of plugin or code that scans a whole site for this data but I'm finding nothing and I don't have a great knowledge of what's out there.

I've tried googling this but I'm not seeing anything that exactly addresses my issue. I have seen a few posts that scan for a single page's image sizes, or for a whole post's image dimensions based on post id, but nothing that addresses this issue site-wide.

Ideally, I would like to somehow curate the data for a list of featured images. I imagine it being organized like:

```
- Post type the featured image is a part of
  - Location it appears
    - Pixel dimensions at breakpoint
```